# Forgot to fork before cloning git repository

Tags: github, fork, clone, git-push

So what I did, was copy and paste my work. Delete the repository, fork a new repository and git clone that. It didn't recognise it as a git repository so I had to do git init and now everythings a mess and it won't let me git add. Saying changes are "untracked"

Comment: You `git clone`d a repository and it didn't recognize the resulting repository as repository?

Comment: think so, yes thats what it said

Answer (score 1):

A `git clone` would create a folder named after the remote repository.

In that folder (meaning you need to `cd myRepo` into the created root folder), Git will recognize the repository.

Try cloning again, and check the new local cloned repository is properly created.

Comment: tried cloning again. its doing the same thing with untracked content

Comment: forgot to CD in to the repo, thanks!!

Comment: @Yassmine perfect! That should work now.